# Unable to reference element with CSS selector in Python Selenium in nested table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-lab

Having issues with CSS selector with code below - using JupyterLab - I am relatively new to coding as well.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
links = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mainContents tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) a[href*='Super']")
```

Thought it was iframes, but i searched the HTML and it does not show.
Also tried to use xPath, but after checking it looks like this is not the way to keep a reliable piece of code.

Error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".mainContents tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) a[href*='Super']"}
(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

HTML below - actually there are a list of these, that I would like to be able to select and click but haven't got that far yet.
The hyperlink changes login session, and looking up the hyperlink text with find_element_by_partial_link_text also does not seem to work..

```
<li><a href="Reportorama/SuperMasterExcel/custom_report_PO.cfm?CFID=12455678&amp;CFTOKEN=a6a4f7f0b4da4813-800DAD38-F642-08D7-3358A02BDEA57F7F&amp;SWPSORAMA_SYSTEM=ASWPS">Super Master Data (Excel)</a></li>
```

Attached an image of the HTML structure of the site: [Nested href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK5jm.png)

I was thinking that because of the nested tables or columns / format of the site the code is unable to find the element, but I do not know where to start. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, overcomplicated it and just used find element by link instead... much faster as well - albeit not very reliable if the hyperlink changes, but good enough to start

```
SuperMaster = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Super Master Data (Excel)')
SuperMaster.click()
```